# I have a null when using a relative path when reading a FileInputStream

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, properties-file

I am trying to read a .properties file from a class that is in a different folder than this .properties. Firstly, I have used another class with a main (testLogin.java) to see if the paths I use are correct and success!

I used an absolute path to read this file and it hasn't given me any problems, in the same way I've tried using a relative one and everything is correct.

**Absolute path:** "C:\User\Documents\project-web\src\main\config\local\application.properties"

**Relative path:** "src/main/config/local/application.properties"

I don't know if this error can occur because the file .properties is in a folder (src/main/config/development/application.properties) and not in a package as it is said in this post
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238208/properties-files-in-regular-src-folder-okay

In the class that I want to implement this function (login.java) **I use the absolute path** to test and it works for me. I compile, run tomcat and everything is correct. **However when implementing the relative**, I don't :(, compile, run tomcat and get null. Do you know what this could be? I'm using Servlets and Maven for the build. My code:

login.java

```
public void doAction(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
   Properties properties = new Properties();

//Using relative path
   try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream("src/main/config/local/application.properties")){ //null when i test after the deploy of the .war in tomcat. But if I execute into a main class it works. It´s strange because only with tomcat it doesn´t works
       properties.load(is);
       System.out.println(properties.getProperty("enviroment"));
   }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
       e.printstackTrace();
   }catch(IOException e){
       e.printstackTrace();
   }

//Using absolute path
   try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Usuario\\Documents\\project-web\\src\\main\\config\\local\\application.properties")){ //OK
       properties.load(is);
       System.out.println(properties.getProperty("enviroment")); //localhost
   }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
       e.printstackTrace();
   }catch(IOException e){
       e.printstackTrace();
   }
}
```

Structure of my project:

[image: Structure]

Error when i try go in after deploy with mvn tomcat7:run
[image: Error Cmd Tomcat]

Comment: Better to load your files/images as resources:
[Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)
[Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)

Comment: I would like to be able to do it but in the project I am in, it is set as I have shown and I do not have permission to change it :(

Comment: Then you need to 'calculate' the [current directory](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/91-find-the-current-directory-in-java)
 and use `Path` and/or `Paths` to correctly relativise. You should check out `getRealPath` too

Comment: File is not where you think it is.

Comment: Hi! I have tried the routes on a main class as I show in the code and both work, but after deploy the project in tomcat it does not work, it shows null pointer exepction

Comment: If you're determined to access resources as files, you need to ensure that the file is going to be present *after* deployment on the server. Did you do that?

Comment: Instead of showing the structure of the project, we will need to see the structure of the deployed .WAR on the Tomcat server.